# Inner join using native sql and hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am trying to inner join multiple and get as result an entity class **Medecin** so here is the methode :

```
   public Medecin getMedecinByLoginPassword(String login, String password) {
    String sql = "SELECT {m.*},{r.*},{s.*},{c.*} FROM medecin m INNER JOIN role r ON m.idrole = r.idrole INNER JOIN service s ON m.service_idservice = s.idservice INNER JOIN centre c ON s.centre_idcentre = c.idcentre WHERE m.login = :login AND m.password = :password";
    SQLQuery query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.addEntity("m",Medecin.class).addJoin("r", "m.role").addJoin("s", "m.service").addJoin("c", "s.centre").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Medecin.class));
    query.setParameter("login", login);
    query.setParameter("password", password);
    List results = query.list();
    return (Medecin) results.get(0);
}
```

But i get this **Error**

```
GRAVE: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for m on class com.mdsoft.gelt.model.Medecin
at org.hibernate.property.ChainedPropertyAccessor.getSetter(ChainedPropertyAccessor.java:44)
at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:57)
```

how can i get ride from this error

Comment: Does the Medecin class a `setM()` public method?

Comment: no , because i don't work with an attribute called m i don't need it 
it's due to this line i think 
query.addEntity("m",Medecin.class)